# SQL query to match similar customers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find the query in order to match similar customers.

To simplify the situation consider this scenario:

I have a table which contains a customer name and product purchased.
customer name can have multiple purchases of same and different products.
So firstly I can take distinct customer name and product name, so I see all customers and all products they purchased at least once.

Now I want a query to show me a sort of matching customers, according to the product they both purchased, so I want to count the similar products they purchased.

So I want to see for each pair of customers (pairing all the table) the amount of similar product they purchased.

Lets say the raw data is:

```
CustomerName | ProductName
A            | 1
A            | 2
A            | 1
A            | 3
B            | 1
B            | 2
B            | 4
C            | 2
```

Then I want to see the result of:

```
CustomerName1 | CustomerName2 | CountSimilarity
A             | B             | 2
A             | C             | 1
B             | C             | 1
```

And so on for all pairs of customers that have at least 1 similar product purchasing

Any suggestions how to approach this query?

The environment is SQL Server.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a self join approach:

```sql
SELECT t1.CustomerName, t2.CustomerName, COUNT(*) AS CountSimilarity
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.ProductName = t2.ProductName
WHERE
    t1.CustomerName < t2.CustomerName
GROUP BY
    t1.CustomerName, t2.CustomerName;
```

Two records are joined together above if their products match.  Note that the inequality in the `WHERE` clause ensures that customer pairs do not appear in duplicate.

Comment: So can I move the WHERE clause to the ON of the join?
And also it seems to work, just need to modify the count(*) to count(distinct t1.ProductName) :)

Oh! And many thanks!!

Comment: Yes, that will also work as we are doing an inner join here.

Comment: Now is there a way to do it as in analytical function "over partition by"? Because I get an error trying to do count(distinct ..) over (partition by)

Comment: Using `GROUP BY` seems like the correct approach here, as we want to aggregate your original table.  Analytic functions do not seem right here, nor will I attempt such an answer.

Comment: First of all thanks for the help! :)
So here is where the thing getting more interesting, I did that self join approach and I even took it further for a 3rd self inner join which this time with "ON t2.CustomerName = t3.CustomerName and t2.ProductName <> t3.ProductName" And this in order to output other product that customer B purchased and A might be interested with, next to each output record of that I want to spread the "similarity count" you just helped me to build.. and thats why I wondered about the analytic function. What do you think? :)

Comment: I think you should ask another question.  I have answered this one.

Comment: @BogdanPaul Tim answered the question asked.  You should ACCEPT it.  Not only is accepting the answer a token of appreciation for Tim's time and talent, it also indicates to other contributors that there was a resolution.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti That's a great comment.  I'm throwing you some rep.

Comment: Thank you guys! you are right! I do appreciate Tim and you guys comments!

Comment: Guys, I'm very new in this forum, so my apologize of how to use it properly.. you can be also easy with new subscribers :) I found out now how to accept an answer and did so with pleasure. Thanks for your understanding! Bogdan